# Change event color if overlaps happens while dragging in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am building a calendar like this one [fullcalendar external dragging](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.2.0/demos/external-dragging.html). What I want to achieve sounds easy, but I found is not. I need, while dragging one of the external events to one specific day in day view, that if overlapping is detected the event changes its color immediately, but color must switch back if overlapping is no longer detected. I thought that in the drop callback(not dropEvent callback) I could be able to make some sort of comparisson, but looks like if the drop listener were outside of the scope of the calendar because I cant access to the ObjectEvent, or at least I dont know how.
 In essence, change the color while dragging an external event into the calendar if, for instance, overlapping is detected

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a weird requirement. Ideally, the color should be customizable per event.

However, I would suggest something that validates your event. Basically, save the original state of the event object. Trigger a validation when it hovers over a zone. Revert back when you leave the zone.

I'm not exactly sure you to see the list of events already in the day.

It's not a great solution but it should work.

Comment: Sorry, think I went a little ambiguous, please read the second question again. And thanks for your fast response

Comment: I'm not super familiar with jQuery UI. Does it have zones for drag-and-drop and events for entering or leaving the zone?

Comment: I am not  either familiar  with jqueryUI, it was a recommendation. The most generic event I found  is eventDragStart. However it's not related anyhow to the drop action(not dropEvent), which is the one I need to check.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. There is an event which handles it in fullCalendar: EventReceive.
Basically it is called after drop() and is the one that builds the calendar'event object right after the drop event ends.
 So, if you are dragging an external eventObject to the calendar and you need, for instance, checking overlapping for this external object, this is the man, I mean, the event.